# how to connect TypeORM MySQL in NestJs?

Tags: typescript, nestjs, typeorm

There is a plenty of questions about connecting database in NestJs.
But I got have to connect database using only URL(including host, port, database), username, password.
It didn't work, although some people told me that it was a necessary to use `user` instead of `username` or use the URL adding username like this `ex) mysql://localhost:3306/demo?user=test`.
How can I solve the problem? Thanks

```js
  createMainDBTypeOrmOptions(): TypeOrmModuleOptions {
    return {
      type: this.configDBProperties.mainType,
      replication: {
        master: {
          url: 'mysql://localhost:3306/demo?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF8',
          username: this.configDBProperties.mainMasterUsername,
          password: this.configDBProperties.mainMasterPassword,
        },
        slaves: [
          {
            url: 'mysql://localhost:3306/demo?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF8',
            username: this.configDBProperties.mainSlaveUsername,
            password: this.configDBProperties.mainSlavePassword,
          },
        ],
      },
      entities: [School, Student],
    };
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I create the connection to database from the app.module and with an .env file with the env variables that I'm using on those lines of code

```
@Module({
  imports: [
    ConfigModule.forRoot(),
    TypeOrmModule.forRootAsync({
      useFactory: () => ({
        type: 'mysql',
        host: process.env.TYPEORM_HOST,
        port: parseInt(process.env.TYPEORM_PORT) || 3306,
        username: process.env.TYPEORM_USERNAME,
        password: process.env.TYPEORM_PASSWORD,
        database: process.env.TYPEORM_DATABASE,
        entities: [__dirname + '/**/*.entity{.ts,.js}'],
        synchronize: false,
        migrationsTableName: process.env.TYPEORM_MIGRATIONS_TABLE_NAME,
        migrations: [process.env.TYPEORM_MIGRATIONS],
        migrationsRun: process.env.TYPEORM_MIGRATIONS_RUN === 'true'
      })
    }),
...
],
  controllers: [],
  providers: []
})
```

Comment: thank you for your response. I wanted to use only url, username. password tho I knew your solution. anyway I just made the function that split url to (host, database, port) and I made it :)